# Restriction of a $C^k$ function is still $C^k$

Tags: differential-geometry

This might seem like a banal question I've come accross while studying for my Differential Geometry exam, but I don't quite know how to formally write it down.

Suppose $G:V\subset \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ is $C^k$, how should I prove that for a subset $V_1 \subset V$, $G|_{V_1}:V_1\subset \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ is still $C^k$.

Comment: What does this have to do with differential geometry? Remember how differentiability is defined on open subsets of Euclidean spaces, i.e. by the existence of continuous partial derivatives.

Comment: By the definition of differentiability of a function restricted to a set for every $x$ you need to find an open set and a function $F: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $F|_{U\cap V_1}=G|_{U\cap V_1}$, such that $F$ is $C^k$, and given your conditions the choice of $F$ is there.

Comment: @Lost I don't get what you mean